# Is there a way to know how often latex has already run?

Tags: compiling, conditionals, counters, automation, auxiliary-files

A few days ago, I have seen an example of a latex file, that did conditional `\def`s on subsequent runs but I can't find that one again.

I still remember that it was by looking into the `\jobname.aux` do get the number of previous builds.

In my current situation, I'd like to *not* use package `minted` but define its commands to simply use verbatim-environment during the first two builds and using `minted` and its built-in macros for syntaxhighlight in the third run.

How exactly can I get the number of previous latex-runs?

Comment: The traditional way is to write a counter value to the `.aux` file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `.tex` code uses a counter called `NumberOfRuns` and writes its value to the `.aux` file at the end of the document (`\AtEndDocument`). In the beginning of the document, after the `.aux` file is read, the counter value is known and then increased.

It is easy then to react to the current counter value via `\ifnum` or `\ifnumexpr` commands, for example from the `etoolbox` package.

**Note**: If the `.aux` file is deleted, the information is lost.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\newcounter{NumberOfRuns}


\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\setcounter{NumberOfRuns}{\number\value{NumberOfRuns}}
}
}%

\AtBeginDocument{%
\refstepcounter{NumberOfRuns}
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

This document was compiled \theNumberOfRuns~times so far!

\end{document}
```

**Improved version, which shows the query for certain values**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{NumberOfRuns}


\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\setcounter{NumberOfRuns}{\number\value{NumberOfRuns}}
}
}%

\AtBeginDocument{%
\refstepcounter{NumberOfRuns}
}%

\makeatother

\newcommand{\prettyoutput}[1]{%
\ifnumequal{\number\value{#1}}{1}{once}{%
  \ifnumequal{\number\value{#1}}{2}{twice}{%
    \ifnumequal{\number\value{#1}}{3}{thrice}{%
      \number\value{#1}~times%
    }%
  }%
}%
}%

\begin{document}

This document was compiled \prettyoutput{NumberOfRuns} so far!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know, that in English language it should be `once`, `twice`, `three` etc. `times` ;-)

Comment: *I thrice presented him a kingly crown, // Which he did thrice refuse: was this ambition?* (Julius Caesar, Act 3, Scene 2). `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: Oh come on, how many people use `thrice` really :D

Comment: Yeah, that every information in the `.aux`-file is lost when you delete it is quite obvious ;) As far as I can see, during the first run, the counter is 0 until the `\begin{document}`? Or better said, if $n$ is the number of runs, then the counter is $n-1$ in the preambel?

Comment: @NobbZ: No, as the code is written, it is initially set to `1`, since it is `\refstep`ped within `\AtBeginDocument`. When a new counter is defined, how ever, its initial value is `0`, that's true

Comment: Yeah, and I thought, that `\AtBeginDocument` is executed at `\begin{document}`, just like `\AtEndDocument` is run at `\end{document}`

Comment: @NobbZ, yes that's right. So in the first run, the counter has value of `1` right from the start. If it should not have this value, explicitly set it to `-1` in the preamble, directly after its definition, so it will start with `0`, then next `1` etc. or alternatively used `\refstepcounter`  within `\AtEndDocument`